# MS Access - Matching records without single identifier

Tags: database, ms-access

I need to find a way to match records between two tables.  The problem is a single identifier that would make the match very simple isn’t available so I need to find a way to make that match based on some other available information in the records.

In an elementary school all registered/existing students have a Student ID.  It is unique and makes a perfect primary key.  However, any new students entering the school for the coming year do not get a Student ID until they are officially registered.

Before the next school year starts the school invites the new incoming students to be part of a pre-registration assessment program to help determine their current level and needs for the coming school year.  It is at this point that as much data about each prospective student is gathered.  This information is stored in a separate table from the main student information, mostly because there is no official Student ID.  The idea is to merge the pre-registration students and their data into the main student information table(s) once they have an official Student ID assigned to them.

My thinking was to assign these new students a temporary ID just to have a unique identifier for them in case there are name duplications.

My question is how can I match up the temporary ID’s with the real ID’s once the student is assigned one?

Some information that will be gathered in the pre-registration process will include Last Name, First Name, Middle Name, Grade, with Birthday being another possibility (but isn’t included at this time).

Maybe I’m going about this in the wrong way so any suggestions on offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of possible answers to this. One option could be to take the Student ID and create a Temporary ID from it and create the ID number early. On the Student ID side, have an 'active' or 'enrolled' column as a BIT field that doesn't activate until the student is registered. Of course, it's difficult to tell what your data is like (or what you can change) and what sort of process you might use, based on your story, but that could be an option. IMO, you have the right idea for matching if you wanted to go through that process, but that may (in some unlikely scenarios) cause conflicts.

Comment: Don't use the Student ID as primary key. A primary key is only meant to uniquely identify records and should not have any other meaning. Define another primary key and add the student data to your table. If they do enroll and are issued a Student ID, add that the your main table. Next, delete all student data for all students that were not issued a Student ID.

Comment: Is there a need for the `Student ID` to be sequential? It seems to be the simplest solution is to assign a student ID during pre-registration and simply not use the IDs of the students that do not end up registering. Barring that you need a set of fields that will guarantee exact matches. Generally names are not good for that because they can be easily mistyped. The problem is much easier if you can use the pre-registration info as a base for registering students than if you have to work with two completely independently generated tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are exporting information from the main Student Information System, running additional processing in Microsoft Access, then ultimately merging it back into the main system. This being the case, you will have to work with the limitations in the export and merge features, and building your matching logic around what is available there.

**Plan A:** Ideally your Excel export would include some type of primary record identifier from the main system, independent of the Student ID that gets assigned later. (It very likely uses a unique ID internally, even if that is not included in the export file.) You would then use this to match to your records in Microsoft Access.

**Plan B:** If the primary system does not export a unique identifier, then you will need to come up with your best combination of data to uniquely identify the student. How you do this will depend on how many students you are dealing with, and whether the matched data changes in either system. Full name and birthdate is a fairly common way to do this, if that data is complete in the originating system.

With the unique identifier established, I would use two queries in Access. The first would be an update query to assign the Student ID to your Access system as soon as it becomes available in the main system. (Search for matching students that have a Student ID in Excel, but not yet in Access.)

The second query would be an append query to add the new students from the main system into Access. (Where the student in Excel does not match any existing student in Microsoft Access.)

Taking this approach, you would pull the Excel export regularly from the main system and run the above queries to keep your Access system updated. Then when you are ready to merge information back into the main system, you could filter on students in Access that have a Student ID assigned. The actual update of data in the main system might be done through an update query, or perhaps an export from Access that includes the Student ID. (Depending on how your main system merges the incoming data.)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to **merge both tables** into a **single table** of students. This table would have an `AutoNumber` ID column that refers to the student or prospective student. Then you would have another column in this table for the `StudentID` which would be assigned at a later point.

Your forms and reports can then filter the data based on the `StudentID` field to show you either current or prospective students.

Taking this approach means your student data gets entered into one place, and you don't have to worry about trying to repeat information or merge it later. Since a single record represents a single individual, it makes logical sense to me to use a single table.

Comment: You and Rene made similar suggestions, and I hadn't thought of doing it this way.  I like it!!!  But...I still have a question about matching up the autonumbered students to their real Student ID once it is assigned. The information for the students comes to me as an Excel export from the official Student Information System.  The Access file isn't the place where the student data is stored.  It is being used for a separate purpose that the real Student Information System cannot handle.  That means I'm still stuck trying to match what I've got in Access to what comes to me in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification. Since you don't have direct access/control over the data in the main system, the single table probably won't be an option in your case. I have added an additional answer focusing on the matching strategy. Hope you find it helpful!